# How do I push all uncommited and unpushed changes from all my git repos?

Tags: bash, git

I'm trying to migrate computers, so I want to copy all my unmerged changes into git so I can pull them later.

Answer (score 3):

One of the nicest points of git is that a repository is just a bog-standard directory (with some funky contents under `.git`, that is). So the easy answer is to just backup on the old machine and restore on the new one, and you are set. The "new" repo is an exact copy of the "old" one, uncommited changes, local settings (Be careful to copy global/user settings! Check `git config` for details.), upstreams and all.

In my case (new Linux box) I just used [rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) to copy stuff over. Other times I just made a tarball and moved that over via thumbdrive.

Answer (score 0):

#### Get All Unmerged Changed In Repo

```sh
setopt sh_word_split # For zsh
dirs=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -execdir test -d {}/.git \; -prune -print 2>/dev/null)
for dir in $dirs; do
    originalPwd=$(pwd)
    cd $dir
    unclean=$(git status --porcelain)
    unpushed=$(git log --branches --not --remotes)
    [[ $unclean || $unpushed ]] && echo $dir
    cd $originalPwd
done
```

#### Save Changes In All Uncomitted Repos

```sh
setopt sh_word_split # For zsh
dirs=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -execdir test -d {}/.git \; -prune -print 2>/dev/null)
for dir in $dirs; do
    originalPwd=$(pwd)
    cd $dir
    unclean=$(git status --porcelain)
    unpushed=$(git log --branches --not --remotes)
    [[ $unclean || $unpushed ]] && git add . && git commit -m "Uncommited Changes" && git push --all
    cd $originalPwd
done
```